# Invalid controller specified Zend 1.11 with new module directory - can only use IndexController.php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to add a module `api` to my existing Zend 1.x project, and I can only navigate to the new module's index controller, no other controllers seem to be working.

The project is laid out like this:

```
application
  -controllers
  -models
  -modules
    -api
      -controllers
      -models
      -views
      -Bootstrap.php
  -views
```

I've added the following lines to my `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

I've also added this empty Bootstrap class to `/modules/api/`:

```
<?php
class Api_Boostrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {
}

?>
```

in `/modules/api/controllers` I've created an `IndexController.php`:

```
<?php   
class Api_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        echo "REST API - Hello World";
    }

}
 ?>
```

And this works when I navigate to `/api/index`, however when I try and add a new controller called `ProjectController.php` in the same directory as the above `IndexController.php`:

```
<?php   
class Api_ProjectController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        echo "SSP REST API - Project Controller";
    }   
}
?>
```

and try to navigate to the `/api/project` url I get `Invalid controller specified (error)`.

Here are the request parameters for `/api/project`:

```
array (
  'module' => 'api',
  'controller' => 'project',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

It seems like the module is attempting to route to the correct controller/action but Zend isn't able to find the controller in the project tree. Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the `Exception information` and `Stack trace:` of the error.

Answer (score 0):

weird ,If the index controller is loading without any error, then any other controller should also load,try to change index controller's name and check,

try to make sure these things are followed in application .ini,

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =

// Default Application Resource Namespace
appnamespace = "YourPrefix"

resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "modulename"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true
```

Under Application following kind of structure is needed (just tested in my system)

```
    ├───configs
    ├───forms
    ├───layouts
    │   └───scripts
    └───modules
        ├───App
        │   ├───controllers
        │   ├───models
        │   │   └───DbTable
        │   └───views
        │       ├───helpers
        │       └───scripts
        │           
        └───default
            ├───controllers
            ├───models
            │   └───DbTable
            └───views
                ├───helpers
                └───scripts
```

Comment: The problem is that this is an existing application, and quite a big one at that, so I can't go and move directories around and prepend a prefix to all the controllers.